# Xamarin.Mac: MMP : error MM5309: Failed to execute the tool 'clang'

Tags: visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac, xcode14, macos-ventura

Since macOS has been upgraded, I upgraded all development environments (Xcode, etc.) and wanted to build with an existing macOS application software project, but I get the following 2 errors and cannot build.

- macOS Ventura (13.0)
- Xcode 14.1
- Visual Studio for Mac (8.10.25)

```
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
MMP : error MM5309: Failed to execute the tool 'clang', it failed with an error code '1'. Please check the build log for details.
```

I have done a lot of searching, but I have no idea what to do. If anyone knows what to do, I would appreciate any tips you can give me.

Comment: Hope to get a solution from Experts or from Microsoft,  that fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Anoop Vaidya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395941/anoop-vaidya)

Thank you for your comment. I was checking the Xamarin GitHub repository and a similar question was asked most recently.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16616

It seemed that the SDK update had not caught up with Xcode 14.1.

I installed a package that will be officially released shortly and was able to build without any problems.

### Another workarounds:

Temporarily reverting Xcode 14.1 back to Xcode 14.0.1 seems to prevent this problem.

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.10.25 (build 2)

and confirmed that it works.

Comment: Yes, that made to build. But now I am seeing another issue `NSArray` methods like ToList() and FirstOrDefault() are not found and I get many compile time errors. Did you also face this?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya
Sorry, I am not experiencing any problems around `NArray` in my environment. It may be that I am not using `ToList()`. However, I have found a way around this problem by downgrading to Xcode 14.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem
*Mac OS Ventura: 13.0

Xcode: 14.1 (14B47b)

Visual Studio for Mac:  17.4 (build 2406)*
Waiting for the package...

Comment: Temporarily reverting Xcode 14.1 back to Xcode 14.0.1 seems to prevent this problem.

Comment: It is not an answer you should add it as a comment